# Adding Map to Android TAB - Error

Tags: android, fragment, android-maps-v2

I have created an application where I have 3 tabs and in the last one I have added a map, and here is the error because I get an error navigating with the tabs.

Take a look below the code

Tab fragment:

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: gon250.dublinbikes, PID: 22233
                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                        at tabs.Tab3.onCreateView(Tab3.java:32)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
                                                                        at customwidget.SlidingTabLayout$TabClickListener.onClick(SlidingTabLayout.java:287)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Duplicate id 0x7f0d0093, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d0096 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2135)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5801)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                        at tabs.Tab3.onCreateView(Tab3.java:32) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495) 
                                                                        at customwidget.SlidingTabLayout$TabClickListener.onClick(SlidingTabLayout.java:287) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10530) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Class where is comming the error:

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
            //TODO: fix issue with color
            tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.background_material_light));
            tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To be more concrete the error is in the function below in the `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);`

```
private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: #gon250 Please check my answer .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Whats your logcat throws**

> ```
>    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
> ```

My advice , use  **SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment** .

Call `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Call**

```
 GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

**Edit**

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Call**

```
     SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
     GoogleMap mapLocation = mapFragment.getMap();
```