# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I keep getting the following error, when trying to implement a Google Map into my fragment. I have searched for solutions a lot already but can't seem to find anything that works for me.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNeuigkeiten">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNeuigkeiten.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Ernaehrung.Rezepte.Details.RezepteDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rezepte_detail_ansicht"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeErnaehrung">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gesundheit.Details.AerzteDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_aerzte_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeGesundheit">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD4s85XcK5hio9lyxy3mJGQH9Lnu6Oayng"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Map Fragment.

package gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.Gesundheit.Karte;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AerzteFinderFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    public AerzteFinderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        /*mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);*/
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Errorlog:

```
01-25 15:46:34.394 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-25 15:46:34.425 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid-2/lib/x86
01-25 15:46:34.445 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
01-25 15:46:34.445 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
01-25 15:46:34.449 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
01-25 15:46:34.449 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
01-25 15:46:34.471 7566-7581/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
01-25 15:46:34.597 7566-7585/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-25 15:46:34.657 7566-7585/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-25 15:46:34.699 7566-7585/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-25 15:46:34.699 7566-7585/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7099c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-25 15:46:35.327 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=103, given seq=102
01-25 15:46:44.594 7566-7581/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
01-25 15:47:10.724 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/zzad: Making Creator dynamically
01-25 15:47:10.736 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
01-25 15:47:10.756 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
01-25 15:47:10.759 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.maps from APK /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/MapsModule.apk
01-25 15:47:10.759 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Loading module APK /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/MapsModule.apk
01-25 15:47:10.761 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is x86
01-25 15:47:10.762 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
01-25 15:47:10.762 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/native-libs/x86
01-25 15:47:10.778 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8487000
01-25 15:47:10.780 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8489470
01-25 15:47:10.863 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /sdcard/Android/data/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid/cache: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/self/primary/Android/data/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid/cache
01-25 15:47:10.871 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-25 15:47:10.872 7566-7566/gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid, PID: 7566
                                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                        at gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.Gesundheit.Karte.AerzteFinderFragment.onCreateView(AerzteFinderFragment.java:45)
                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                        at gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.Gesundheit.Karte.AerzteFinderFragment.onCreateView(AerzteFinderFragment.java:45) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ao.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2224)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                        at gvapp.diplomprojekt.at.gv_appandroid.Gesundheit.Karte.AerzteFinderFragment.onCreateView(AerzteFinderFragment.java:45) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-25 15:52:10.919 7566-7566/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7566 SIG: 9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994730/adding-map-to-android-tab-error/34994754#34994754

Comment: Didnt't work unfortunately, getting the same error.

Comment: same logcat returns ?????/

Comment: call `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Well, not exactly the same. The first 2 Exceptions are again 'InflateExceptions'. The 3rd one is 'android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment', the 4th one 'java.lang.ClassCastException'. But if I use a v4 Fragment, I can't embed the it in my MainActivity.